# How convert int to null because validate property dont raise button

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I make database using entity framework. I make in database int Time nullable

```
        public int? Time { get; set; }
```

But in my app when i try leave textbox validate property say "Cant convert to "". ". How avoid this?

I dont know how explain this but i have wrapper where is validation. When i leave int Time empty, validation say "Cant convert to ""." like in picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqs7b.jpg
So i cant save when its empty but database can save nullable int.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make any sense to me, could you please be more specific as well as include the code that's actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbox returns as an empty string, not as a null, so the validator cannot convert this empty string to (int?).
Because you did not provide the validator part of your code, all I can say, that you have to handle it in the validator: if the Time textbox is an empty string, then pass the validation, and set the value in db to null.
Can you provide the codepart, where you validate this field? Did you try it with a validator attribute?

Comment: This work i TargetNullType in xaml to '' and in wrapper make int? on prop and get. Now it work so now i can save thanks!